# Cordova Geolocation Timeout

Tags: android, cordova, gps

I have this weird problem. My code is the following:

```
 var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 30000 });
```

Either I have enableHighAccuracy true or false my APP will return code 3 timeout IF the device GPS is not set to High Accuracy. How can I solve this problem ? If on a device I have High Accuracy GPS enabled it will work just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the GPS state before you use it. You can do it by using the cordova-plugins-diagnostic  plugin:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic#islocationavailable